# Is it possible to reclaim Private_Clean pages?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, shared-memory, lmdb

I have a process that has to read a bunch of stuff from a mmap()ed file and then does memory intensive processing of some of this data (discarding the mmaped data as it gets processed). In my case, the mmaped file is from LMDB. After I mmap the file, I get something like this:

```
7fc32f29b000-7fc50c000000 rw-s 00000000 fc:02 75628978                   /tmp/.tmp5SYf4y/data.mdb
Size:            7812500 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:              285516 kB
Pss:              285516 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:    285516 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:       285516 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:           285516 kB
```

Let's say the process has only 300000kB of physical RAM, limited by cgroups (and may or may now have available swap).
I understand that since all memory pages are Locked (pinned), they cannot be swapped out. After mmap()ing the file (i.e. reading from LMDB), the process then starts allocating more memory, beyond (`physical RAM - Shared_Clean`) in the output above. Can these Shared_clean pages be evicted and reclaimed by the memory pressure of the new allocations from the same process?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: the answer is yes, clean mmaped pages are reclaimed when there's a memory pressure from within the same process.

To demonstrate this, I added a loop that allocates heap memory after the LMDB file has been mmaped. I ran the process under a cgroup limiting the RSS by the mmaped file size.  Then `/proc/<pid>/smaps` shows that the Clean_Pages RSS of the mmaped file starts dropping when the program goes into heap allocation loop, and the heap RSS / pages start growing correspondingly.